# LinkedIN OAuth log in trouble Nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api, passport.js

I am using LinkedIn OAuth and passport for my sign in. For whatever reason the first time I try to log in, it routes to homepage without logging in. The second time however, it logs in properly. What might be causing this problem? LinkedIn or passport?

This is the get path :

```
router.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash:true}),
function (req, res, next) {

    User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
            res.redirect("/")
        }
        user.last_login = moment();
        user.save()
        return res.redirect('/profile/' + user.username);
    });
});
```

And then the passport linkedIn :

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
   clientID: config.linkedin.consumerKey,
   clientSecret: config.linkedin.consumerSecret,
   callbackURL: config.linkedin.callbackURL,
   state: true,
   scope: ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']}, function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
```

...